# Multiselect Dropdown - Display Selected Data on Button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a multiselect dropdown that fetches data from the database. There are preselected data that I need to display on page load instead of displaying the "Please Select" word. I am using angularjs and javascript. How can I possibly do that. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group col-md-6 pull-right">
   <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  >---Please select---{{item.skin_type_name}}<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="item in SkinType">
            <input type="checkbox" id={{item.skin_type_id}} name="NAME2" value="{{item.skin_type_id}}" ng-checked="skintypeID[item.skin_type_id]==item.skin_type_id" ng-click="skntypclk(item.skin_type_id)" ng-disabled="currreadstypepro==1" ng-required="curstyp==1"><label>{{item.skin_type_name}}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I am using an API fetching data from the database and it looks like this one:

```
editorService.editSkintype(id)
            .then(function(data){
                $rootScope.loadercount--;
                console.log($rootScope.loadercount);
                skintypeIDArr = {};
                angular.forEach(data.data, function(value) {
                    angular.forEach(value, function(value, key) {
                        if(key == "skin_type_id"){
                            skintype[value] = value;
                            skintypeIDArr[value] = value;
                        }
                    });
                });
                $scope.skintypeID = skintypeIDArr;
            })
```

How can I display the preselected value on button instead of Please select? The data can only be displayed once I edit the values but what i need is to display the preselected value on page load. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the currently selected item in the scope. so the HTML would be:

```
<div class="btn-group col-md-6 pull-right">
   <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">{{selectedItem.skin_type_name}}<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="item in SkinType">
            <input type="checkbox" id={{item.skin_type_id}} name="NAME2" value="{{item.skin_type_id}}" ng-checked="skintypeID[item.skin_type_id]==item.skin_type_id" ng-click="skntypclk(item.skin_type_id)" ng-disabled="currreadstypepro==1" ng-required="curstyp==1"><label>{{item.skin_type_name}}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If so, then in your controller you could simply load the default value and then run the API call:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedItem = {
        skin_type_name: "Preselected Data"
    };
    // Now run the API call...
});
```

This way the preselected data will be set when the controller is loaded.

If you need it to be outside the controller, then declare the `selectedItem` in the `$rootScope` instead.